# Question about Inheritance Hierarchy without any virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Imagine if I have class hierachy like this (Inheritance Hierarchy A):

```
Vehicle 
     MotorVehicle
         Automobile 
         Motorcycle 
     WaterCraft 
         Sailboat
          Canoe
```

If the `Vehicle` class contains functions named `get_retail_price()` and `get_description()`, and the `get_description()` function is overridden by every subclass in the hierarchy, without a virtual function in the base class, which `get_description()` function is executed by the following code?

```
void display_vehicle(const Vehicle& v) 
{
    std::cout << "Description: " << v.get_description() << ‘\n’ 
              << "Retail price: " << v.get_retail_price() << "\n\n"; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    Motorcycle motorcycle("Harley-Davidson FXDR 114", 21349.0);   
    display_vehicle(motorcycle); 

    return 0;
}
```

I think it is the one in the `Vehicle` class because every subclass is redefining the `get_descritption()` function. But it the `Vehicle` class that calls it. Am I right to assume this?

And last question, what would happen if `display_vehicle(const Vechicle& v)` had a return type of any class? Something like `Automobile display_vehicle(const Vehicle& v)`. Will it still call `get_description()` in the `Vehicle` class?

Comment: `had a type of any class object` what do you mean by that? A template? Function overloading? `std::any`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I meant something like Motorcycle display_vehicle(const Vehicle& v). Don't even know if that is possible.

Comment: I don't quite understand what this imaginary syntax would do. I assume something like duck-typing? What I mean is a function that accepts anything as parameter as long as the object sent support the right operation?

Comment: Sorry, so it is something wrong. I was saying that rather than it being `void` what if the return type of some class. Sorry, OOP concepts are weak at the moment.

Comment: It's okay. Dynamic polymorphism is hard in the beginning. There is also static polymorphism, which would make the `display_vehicule` a function template, but it a whole another world.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot thanks for replying, okay I gotcha, will look into static polymorphism more. What resource you personally used when you were learning c++ and OOP sir?

Comment: mostly trial and error, stack overflow and blog posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For member functions that are not virtual, it's the function of the known type that is invoked.

Here, the only known type is `Vehicle`:

```
void display_vehicle(const Vehicle& v) 
{
    std::cout << "Description: " << v.get_description() << ‘\n’ 
              << "Retail price: " << v.get_retail_price() << "\n\n"; 
}
```

Note by the way that in such a case, you don't override the funcions.  But you define a new function which hides the function of the base class.

If the function would be virtual, it would be the function of the object's real type that would be called.

Here a small snippet to show the different cases:

```
class Vehicle {
public:  
    virtual void show() { cout<<"I'm a vehicle"<<endl; }   // virtual
    void print() { cout <<"I'm a vehicle"<<endl; }         // not virtual
    void invokeshow() { show(); }                          // not virtual but invoking virtual
    void invokespecificshow() { Vehicle::show(); }         // not virtual invoking specific
    ~Vehicle() {}                                //at least one virtual ?  then virtual destructor
}; 

class Motorcycle: public Vehicle {
public:  
    void show() override { cout<<"I'm a motorcycle"<<endl; }
    void print() { cout <<"I'm a motorcycle"<<endl; }
}; 

void test(Vehicle &v) {
    v.show(); 
    v.print();
    v.invokeshow(); 
    v.invokespecificshow(); 
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/hQrGIf)

Comment: Uhhh..that makes sense. So if subclass did have a `virtual` keyword, get_description() would come from Motorcycle class? Yeah?

Comment: @ChoraMor -- no; the subclass can't impose virtualness. It's `Vehicle` that has to mark the function virtual.

Comment: @Christophe & Pete Becker. It is my fault. I meant to say superclass. My apologies. Also, what are your personal favorite resources to learn OOP materials?

Comment: @ChoraMora No.  FOr virtual to work, you'd need the function to be already virtual for the class on which you call it (so here Vehicle).

Comment: @Christophe Ok, I am really sorry. Terminology is very weak at the moment. I did understand you friend.